# Why availablePermits() function not give me right result in my code | Java Threads | Semaphore |

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, semaphore

In my code the threads available permits is 5 and I use acquire(int permits) function to reduce the permits up to 2 but when I run my code 
the first thread give me 3 it make sense but when the next thread executed the available permits is 1, So why this is happening I don't understand Please help me I'm new in java.

Here is mY code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class HelpMe
{
  private Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(5);

  void question()
  {
    try
    {
      sema.acquire(2);
      System.out.println("Available permits : " + sema.availablePermits());
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      sema.release(2);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.getMessage();
    }
  }
}

class JavaExperts implements Runnable
{
  private HelpMe help_me;

  JavaExperts(HelpMe help_me)
  {
    this.help_me = help_me;
  }

  @Override public void run()
  {
    help_me.question();
  }
}

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HelpMe help_me = new HelpMe();
    Thread one = new Thread(new JavaExperts(help_me));
    Thread two = new Thread(new JavaExperts(help_me));
    Thread three = new Thread(new JavaExperts(help_me));
    Thread four = new Thread(new JavaExperts(help_me));
    one.start();
    two.start();
    three.start();
    four.start();
  }
}
```

The output is :

Available permits : 1

Available permits : 3

Available permits : 3

Available permits : 1

Code image : [code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqza9.png)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that these two lines:

```
sema.acquire(2);
System.out.println("Available permits : " + sema.availablePermits());
```

can be executed by different threads. What I mean is that `Thread1` might call `sema.acquire(2)` and *before* it reaches `System.out.println`, `Thread2` might call that `ema.acquire(2)` *again*, only after that the `System.out.println` from `Thread1` would be executed.

You have a single instance of `HelpMe` that is shared among all those threads and because there are 5 permits available and you only acquire two (meanign 3 are left), any subsequent thread is free to acquire two more; thus two threads are free to execute that code.

Answer (score 2):

This semaphore `private Semaphore sema=new Semaphore(5);` allows 5 'units', when a thread try to adquire at `try{ sema.acquire(2);` the available 'units' will be `5 - 2`. Then another thread try to adquire at `try{ sema.acquire(2);` and the available 'units' will be `5 - 2 - 2`. At this moment, the available 'units' are `1` and the other threads try to adquires `2`, so there isn't enoght available 'units' and this other threads will be blocked until there is at least 2 units available at `try{ sema.acquire(2);`.  When one of this threads release 2 'units' at `sema.release(2);`, the available 'units' will be `5 - 2 -2 + 2` and another thread could adquire '2 units' at `try{ sema.acquire(2);`.

At the same time, two threads can be inside this lines:

```
  System.out.println("Available permits : " + sema.availablePermits());
  Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Printed messages are not sorted at this point, so there a race conditions that allows this behaviour.